# How do i append every result from loop in his own slide jQuery Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Helo, i am working with my plugin and i would like to show every result from plugin script in his own slide in Bootstrap carousel. 
My HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides. "Item" and "item active" is just for showing how this slider works -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/fullimage1.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/fullimage2.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>


      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

My plugin script:

```
self.buildHtml = function(results){

        var limit = self.options.maxMatches;

        $.each(results.doc, function(){
            for(var i =0; i< this.data[0]['realcategories'].length; i++){
                var RealCategory = this.data[0]['realcategories'][i];
                var realcategoryName = RealCategory.name;
                for(var j= 0; j< RealCategory.tournaments.length; j++){
                    var tournamentName = RealCategory.tournaments[j].name;
                    var seasonTypeName = RealCategory.tournaments[j].seasontypename;

                        self.append('<div class="item active">'tournamentName+' - '+ seasonTypeName +'</div>');

                    limit--;

                    if (limit <= 0) {
                        return false;
                    };
                };
            };
        });

    };
```

If i leave `self.append('<div class="item active">'tournamentName'</div>');`
i get all result in one slide. I know other results should be in `class="item"`but i don't know how to do this.
Here i call plugin:

```
$('.carousel-inner').matchCarousel();
```

Result i get.[image: results]What i want is each of these items to be in his own slide.That mean 10 slides.Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: The `self.append` line is broken. You have the "+" inside of the string. Get rid of the "+" and the ' before the closing `div`. Also, can you show your complete javascript. I have no idea where `RealCategory` comes from.

Comment: So, did that fix your issue or not, @userDC? If not: what's `self` in this context? Also, open up your web inspector console and share the actual error message that you get.

Comment: No, @Bjorn, i did not fix the issue yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/1kz4ssn3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [
    'Primeria Division',
    'Eredivisie'
  ];

  var carousel = $('#myCarousel');

  $(items).each(function(k) {
    $('.carousel-inner', carousel).append('<div class="item"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="><div class="container"><div class="carousel-caption"><h1>'+this+'</h1></div></div></div>');

    $('.carousel-indicators', carousel).append('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+k+'"></li>');
  });

  $('.carousel-indicators li:first, .carousel-inner div.item:first', carousel).addClass('active');
  $(carousel).carousel();
});
```

What I'm basically doing is looping through the array of tournaments and then create both a `div.item` and `li.carousel-indicator` for it. After looping through the array, I'm making the first item active and initialize the carousel.